# Plot 2 different metrics with 2 different y axis scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot my data using 2 different y axis. There have been similar questions but the solution doesn't work for me.

my data is similar to this:

```
d<- data.frame(location = c("Italy", "Italy", "Germany","Germany", "France", "France"),
               label = c("Test","Control","Test","Control", "Test","Control"),
               a = c(2000,3000, 3000, 4000, 2500, 3500),
               b = c(1.5,2,2.5,2, 1.8, 3))
```

For now this is my solution:

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = location))
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(y = a, fill = label, group = label, colour = label), stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
p <- p +geom_line(aes(y = b, group = label, colour = label), stat="identity", size = 0.8)+ geom_point(aes(y = b, group = label, colour = label), stat="identity")
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . /2000, name = "b"))+ scale_color_manual(values=c('#7E261A','#15656A'))
```

I need to compare the values between Test and control group, which is hwy I am using `group = label, colour = label), stat="identity"`
However, the secondary metric(b) does't show as intended.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you still need to scale your data because you can only use one base plot.
In this post Hadley gives good reasons not to use it.
[ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
d<- data.frame(location = c("Italy", "Italy", "Germany","Germany", "France", "France"),
               label = c("Test","Control","Test","Control", "Test","Control"),
               a = c(2000,3000, 3000, 4000, 2500, 3500),
               b = c(1.5,2,2.5,2, 1.8, 3))


p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = location))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = a, fill = label, group = label, colour = label), 
           stat = "identity",position = "dodge")+
  geom_line(aes(y = b*1000, group = label, colour = label), size = 0.8)+
  geom_point(aes(y = b*1000, group = label, colour = label), stat="identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . /1000, name = "b"))+ 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#7E261A','#15656A'))

p
```

Comment: Hadley went to great lengths to prevent this kind of dual-axis plot using ggplot because of the likelihood of confusion.  Better to scale (this answer) or use facets and scale = "free_y"

Comment: But label the axes much better.  As-is it is very confusing.